# How do I match double backslash in a single-quoted string?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to distinguish between string with single and double backslashes. Perl treats them equally:

```
print "\n" . '\qqq\www\eee\rrr';
print "\n" . '\\qqq\www\eee\rrr';
```

will give the same result:

```
\qqq\www\eee\rrr
\qqq\www\eee\rrr
```

Even more, the next calls:

```
print "\n" . leadingBackSlash('\qqq\www\eee\rrr');
print "\n" . leadingBackSlash('\\qqq\www\eee\rrr');
print "\n" . leadingBackSlash('\\\qqq\www\eee\rrr');
print "\n" . leadingBackSlash('\\\\qqq\www\eee\rrr');
```

to function :

```
sub leadingBackSlash {
    $_ = shift;
    print "\n$_";
    print "\n" . length($_);

    if( m/^\\\\/) {
        print "\ndouble backslash is matched";
    }

    if( m/^\\/) {
        print "\nsingle backslash is matched";
    }
}
```

will produce result :

```
\qqq\www\eee\rrr
16
single backslash is matched

\qqq\www\eee\rrr
16
single backslash is matched

\\qqq\www\eee\rrr
17
double backslash is matched
single backslash is matched

\\qqq\www\eee\rrr
17
double backslash is matched
single backslash is matched
```

i.e. it matches double backslash as single one.

Could you please help me with regexp to match double but not single backslash?

Comment: Try: `/^\\(?:[^\\]|$)/`

Comment: Thank you! negative lookahead is an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Perl, single quoted strings have just two backslash escapes:

1. The delimiter, e.g. `'John\'s car'`.
2. The backslash. This is neccessary when we want a trailing backslash: `'foo\bar\\'`

All other backslashes are literal. The unfortunate consequence of this is, that for *n* actual backslashes, either *2n-1* or *2n* backslashes must be used in your single quoted string literal.

Regexes have the same backslash semantics as double quoted strings.

You already have a regex that matches a leading double backslash: `/^\\\\/`. This obviously won't match a single leading backslash.

If you want to match a single backslash, and a single backslash only, just make sure that the first backslash is not followed by another one. This uses a negative lookahead: `/^\\(?!\\)/`.

Comment: The single-quote variant of heredocs counts differently: *n* backslashes are always *n* backslashes. This lets you get around the annoying escaping altogether. Example `print <<'';␤\\\\␤␤` will print 4 backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

#Give the STDIN from the commandline and you will get the exact output

chomp (my $string = <STDIN>) ; # Input: \\\arun
print "\$string: ".$string,"\n";
if($string =~m/^(\\.*?)[a-z]+/i){print "Matched backslash ".length ($1)."
times in the string ".$string."\n";}

my $string2 = '\\\arun';
print "\$string2: ".$string2,"\n";


=h
output:

Inputgiven:\\\arun
$string: \\\arun
Matched backslash 3 times in the string \\\arun
$string2: \\arun
```

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to *explain* what you are doing, and why you are doing it this way. (Also note that frankly, your regex is bullshit. You probably meant `/^(\\*)/`. E.g. with your regex, if I had the literal input `\\: foobar`, the `$1` capture would be equal to `"\\\\: "`, giving the length *4*. You do not wish to quantify the `.`, but the ``\\ ``. Also, `/...[a-z]+/i` is ridiculous. Don't you mean `\w+`?)