# Per https Authentication fails

Tags: perl, https

I have a few problems authenticating to a website via Perl.
I can login to the website without any problems using a browser, if I do, it shows me a little prompt, where I have to supply my credentials.
Easy going!

But now I wanted to connect to the site by using the script and I am always running into a 401 unauthorized error.

The server I am trying to connect to runs IIS7 and the WWW-Authenticate header told me, the realm would be something like 'negotiate, NTLM' (I tried all three possibilities, one of the words or both, nothing happened).

So far I really don't know how to figure out what information is needed, my last try was to get the form, where I have to supply the credentials and then use the submit_form function, but to get the forms, I have to establish the connection.

I am really confused because I tried most of the things I found on google, but I don't know what is going on, especially from the technical view, which could give me a hint.

Well, I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me and I thank you in advance for doing it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Authen::NTLM;

my $url = "some.url";
my $usr = 'bernd';
my $pwd = 'bernd';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(ssl_opts => {verify_hostname => 0});
$mech -> credentials($url.":443","NTLM",$usr,$pwd);

$mech->get("https://".$url); #added the https, because $url doesn't have it
print $mech->forms;
```

PS:
The bypassing of ssl verification was due to a certificate problem I had at the beginning.

Comment: It is not possible to test this program. What is the real URL? – Do not delete your questions if you do not like the comments or answers. It makes people reluctant to help you again.

Comment: I didn't delete anything, don't know what you mean.
The problem is, that it's a internal url, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You asked, then deleted http://stackoverflow.com/q/17964806 when it was already answered. I am unhappy about that. The page is still [visible to users with a high reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say and I know it sounds like a kiddy excuse, but I did not delete that post. I'm very confused how tha could happen, maybe I should avoid letting stackoverflow to keep me logged in. I really don't know, but I will keep in mind what you said, so I won't make the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that in your use of the [4 parameter form of the `credentials` method](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#ua-credentials-netloc-realm-uname-pass), the netloc and user are wrong.

When the URL is `https://www.example.com/foo/bar?quux;baz=42#fnord`, the netloc is `www.example.com:443`.

The user is a string of the NTLM domain, a single backslash, and the NTLM username, e.g. `internal\bernd`. Mind that if you hardcode that value as a string literal as you did in the example, you need to [escape the backslash with a backslash](http://p3rl.org/data#Scalar-value-constructors).

Check for these possible errors.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I tried to alter the url but nothing changes. For the backslash problem I simply used the single quotes ' ' , that should be sufficient, shouldnt it?

Comment: Could it be possible that the IIS needs a specific header to recognize what kind of credentials are supplied? I think I have read something about heavy differences between apache and IIS.

Comment: Changing the URL is wrong. You need to change the netloc, which is the first parameter of `credentials`. – You must to escape a backslash with a backslash even in single quoted string literals. Do read the documentation I have linked to. [The only exception is heredocs with single quoted end tokens.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17845606#comment26068896_17845671)

Comment: No, NTLM authentication works the same on IIS as on any other Web server. There are the `Authorization` or `Proxy-Authorization` and `WWW-Authenticate` headers, which are all standardised in the HTTP RFCs. When you use Mech/LWP correctly, all this works transparently. – Try setting the realm parameter to an empty string.

Comment: I did everything you said, escaped the backslash and emptied the Realm field, which gave me following error: "The keep_alive option must be enabled for NTLM authentication to work.  NTLM authentication aborted." I read something about a ConnCache object, so I created one like this: `$agent->conn_cache(LWP::ConnCache->new());` But it tells me it can not locate it in the package. Is this part of another module?

Comment: Wrong, too much work. Just set the `keep_alive` option in the constructor: `->new(keep_alive => 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the problem is not a script or Perl problem as it seems, some of the developers of the site did a really shitty job with the permissions, so you have to be authorized to view everything else, in order to view the single site and the service account I were told to use, does not have this permissions.

Very sad, but thanks for the help so far!